# I cannot load a custom shape in Rappid/jointJS using function fromJSON

Tags: load, shapes, jointjs, rappid, stencils

In my Stencil I have many shapes of type basic.Circle which work great so far with codes similar to the following one:

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
    size: { width: 5, height: 3 },
    attrs: {
        circle: { width: 50, height: 30, fill: '#602320' },
        text: { text: 'START', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
    }
})
```

For example this code creates this shape:

[image]

Now I want to create a shape with exactly the same attributes but with setting a specific type inside the definiition of this shape (**`type: "basic.Jump"`**)

As a result the new code will be the following:

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
    type: 'basic.Jump',
    size: { width: 5, height: 5 },
    attrs: {
        circle: { width: 50, height: 30, fill: '#1E90FF' },
        text: { text: 'Jump', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
    }
})
```

When I add this shape to paper it renders great and looks like this:

[image]

This shape can be successfully saved as JSON but it cannot be loaded using function `fromJSON` and the Console error is the following:

[image]

How should I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem via a very clever way:

Since my problem was that I couldn't load my graph which consisted of shapes `basic.Jump` , now before loading my graph via function `fromjson` I turn the type of these shapes to basic.Circle so as to be able to render the graph and after successfully rendering the graph I set them again to `basic.Jump`

And now I can Save/Load graphs without this error.

Comment: A cleaner way is not to use built-in `type` attribute but introduce your own attribute. e.g. `shapeType: "jump".`

Comment: Thanks Roman. I should use built-in attribute 'type' for so far I parse a JSON of my graph using this attribute for many purposes. Thus my custom solution seems to bw working fine so far.